# Button Submit calls Onload first!

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with a webform.

**My Goal:** Intially when a page is loading, it has to load every textbox empty. After filling the info and click submit, it has to get submitted(UpdatePaymentInfo())

**Problem:** Here, When the user fills the info and clicks Submit,it calls onload function even before the submit button and makes all text box empty.

Here is the code:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    string QueryStringupdatecreditcard1 = Request.QueryString.ToString();

    if (String.Equals(QueryStringupdatecreditcard1, "tabID=B"))
    {
        divTitle.Visible = false;
        trmain.Visible = false;
        tdOrderSummary.Visible = false;
        trCCandBilling.Visible = true;
        trtest2.Visible = false;
        divUpdatecreditcard.Visible = true;
        trusecompaddress.Visible = false;

        txtFirstName.Text = "";
        txtLastName.Text = "";
        txtAddress1.Text = "";
        txtAddress2.Text = "";
        txtCity.Text = "";
        txtZip.Text = "";
        txtCardNo.Text = "";
        txtVccNumber.Text = "";
        trAmountCharged.Visible = false;
    }
}

protected void imgbtnSubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        UpdatePaymentInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the irritating world of web forms :)  Check out the ASP .NET implementation of MVC sometime, it make a whole lot more sense than web forms.  (I comment instead of answer because there are already plenty of answers, all of which illustrate the recommended "solution" of wrapping your code in conditionals and pretending it's OK.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the current contents of your OnLoad method in:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // Code in here will only be executed when the page is *not* being loaded by a postback
}
```

This is because, as per the [ASP.NET Page Life Cyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), the things that you care about in this instance happen in this order:

> *Load* - During load, if the current request is a postback, control
>   properties are loaded with information
>   recovered from view state and control
>   state.
>
> *Postback event handling* - If the request is a postback, control event
>   handlers are called. After that, the
>   Validate method of all validator
>   controls is called, which sets the
>   IsValid property of individual
>   validator controls and of the page.

So what happens is (somewhat simplified):

1. You click the image button, triggering the postback.
2. The data from your form is loaded into your controls.
3. Your OnLoad method overwrites the values in the controls to clear them.
4. Your click handler is run, but because of step 3 it sees empty values.

As others have *sort-of* mentioned, it wouldn't necessarily be a bad thing to refactor your OnLoad method whilst you're doing this. At the moment you seem to have it doing two distinct things:

- Clearing the text fields
- Setting the visibility of fields

It might be worth separating this into one or two (depending on if the visibility setting and field clearing will be done independently) separate methods and adjusting your OnLoad method so it looks like this:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if (!Page.IsInPostBack)
    {
        SetFieldVisibility();
        ClearFields();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Page_Load always occurs.

See the documentation on the [Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

What you need to do is check to see if the Page_Load is being triggered by a Postback.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       ///do stuff in here that you want to occur only on the first lad.
    }
    else
    }
       // code that you want to execute only if this IS a postback here.
    {

 }

// do stuff you want to do on Page_Load regardless of postback here.
}
```

Comment: +1 from me (reciprocaton time =), for mentioning the Page Lifecyle, it prompted me to add it, plus the relevant bit and a "walk-through" to my answer =)

Comment: You also have a small typo in the line immediately above your code snippet.. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property of the Page as follows:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
  if (!Page.IsPostBack) { 
    EmptyTextBoxes();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping the form reset code in a check to see if the page is a postback?

```
if(!Page.IsPostback) {
    // Do form reset here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You thought about using the [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) page variable?

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack){
      //all your logic here.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's the case, you might use a databound control and set it to insert mode